# Can not install TensorBoard as Keras callback

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I get the following error when attempting to create a TB callback.

I am using PlaidML in a Keras sequential model in a Jupiter notebook in MacOS 10.15.7 with
Keras version 2.2.4, &
TensorFlow 2.4.1

```
import plaidml.keras
plaidml.keras.install_backend()
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'plaidml.keras.backend'

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

import numpy as np
import pathlib
import PIL
import PIL.Image

# tensorflow for TensorBoard
import tensorflow

logs_dir = '/Users/x/TensorFlowFolder/logs'
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

callbacks_list = [
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor='val_loss',
        patience=2,
    ),
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        'best_modelFour.h5', 
        monitor='val_loss', 
        verbose=1, 
        save_best_only=True
    ),
    keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
        log_dir=logs_dir,
        histogram_freq=0,
        write_graph=True, write_images=True
    )
]
```

The Error chain is

```
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py
> in __init__(self, log_dir, histogram_freq, batch_size, write_graph,
> write_grads, write_images, embeddings_freq, embeddings_layer_names,
> embeddings_metadata, embeddings_data, update_freq)
>     744             import tensorflow as tf
> --> 745             from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
>     746         except ImportError:
> 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-4-93b8c44b3056> in <module>
>      15         save_best_only=True
>      16     ),
> ---> 17     keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
>      18         log_dir=logs_dir,
>      19         histogram_freq=0,
> 
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py in
> __init__(self, log_dir, histogram_freq, batch_size, write_graph, write_grads, write_images, embeddings_freq, embeddings_layer_names,
> embeddings_metadata, embeddings_data, update_freq)
>     745             from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
>     746         except ImportError:
> --> 747             raise ImportError('You need the TensorFlow module installed to '
>     748                               'use TensorBoard.')
>     749 
> 
> ImportError: You need the TensorFlow module installed to use
> TensorBoard.
```

TensorBoard is apparently trying to get the module Projector from TensorFlow.contrib. TensorFlow.contrib has apparently been removed from TensorFlow for quite some time. The second error appears to be spurious since TF is successfully installed.  I imagine that if this really broke TensorBoard there would be a big squawk, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's recommended to use tf.keras instead of keras package. That way versions always line up

Answer (score 1):

Keras 2.2 does not support TensorFlow 2. Excerpt from the [release of the 2.2.5](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.2.5):

> Keras 2.2.5 is the last release of Keras that implements the 2.2.* API. It is the last release to only support TensorFlow 1 (as well as Theano and CNTK).

Downgrade your TensorFlow version to the 1.15.

Comment: First priority in this project is to train with GPU acceleration. I found a 10-20x flow boost with the Radeon 5500 on my MacBook Pro.  So how can one then use TensorBoard when using GPU acceleration with  PlaidML which does not support tf.keras, only "standalone" Keras? Are we constrained to wait for Intel to migrate Plaid to the TF.Keras framework??

Comment: You can use the tensorboard, just install TF1.x and a compatible version of the Tensorboard. Or you can wait for intel to hypothetically add support to TF2.